# How to create routing proxy for every request to a WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi 2 API whose URL I want to keep private/internal. I also have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project which will use this API using JavaScript. What I would like to do is create a single controller action for every API request made by AJAX. The AJAX request should be made to this controller action, the action should decide which API endpoint it should call, make the request and return the result. I want to accomplish this with a single action since I don't want to have duplicates of the endpoints in the API in the MVC project. Very similar to what `System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService` does for WCF. How can I accomplish this?